# I just got my dupehammer but I have have to wait 9 more days to use it

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, dupehammer

I just got my [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) dupehammer privilege. Shortly after that I got a message from an OP reminding me about a previous vote-to-close I had made on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-color-part-of-a-textview) on January 31 7:17. So I thought I would put my dupehammer to use. However, when I tried, I got

> You have already voted to close this question, but you may vote again in 9 days

This is a fringe problem, but it seems like the wait should be cancelled once someone has the dupehammer. (I know I don't have to wait to use my dupehammer on other questions that I haven't voted previously on.)

*Full disclosure: I have an answer on this particular dupe target. But the reason is, I found several similar open questions. I added my answer to the question that I thought was best, and then voted to close the other ones. (also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext))*

Comment: If you had used your dupe hammer on that post before and it was re-opened, *you'd get the same message*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Interesting. That makes sense, though, because if it was reopened there is a very real possibility that I closed it wrongly. Here, I think my original non-dupehammer vote probably just got lost in the [crowd](http://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope, he couldn't have voted for the same post again in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you voted to close a question and that vote aged away, that means that you [have to wait 14 days to recast it again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/213575), that applies to any close vote, including duperhammer.

> 1. **Start aging votes after 14 days**, regardless of view count. That is, if the newest vote on the question is 14 days old, aging will begin even if the view threshold has not been exceeded. If the view threshold is exceeded sooner, then the existing time threshold (4 days since newest vote) will be used instead.
> 2. **Allow re-casting votes that've aged away after 14 days.** That is, 14 days (use the same site-configurable value used in #1 here) after your vote has aged away, you're free to cast the same vote again.

Basically, you had a close vote that aged 5 days prior and was casted at least 4 to 14 days before that.